# How do you display rapidly updating data to the user in a win32 GUI app?

Tags: c++, c++11, winapi, visual-studio-2015

So im building a basic win32 GUI app and I have a vector of data that gets constantly updated through an external source via a port.  Im interested in displaying that list of data to the user but im not sure the best approach to go about it without causing update flickering.

I originally had an edit box in which I build a string with the information and update the window. But it has proved troublesome as the amount of data grows since I cant scroll down to look at additional data.  Any ideas?

Comment: "*it has proved troublesome as the amount of data grows since I cant scroll down to look at additional data*" - yes, you can, if you use a multi-line Edit control, and send it an [`EM_SCROLLCARET`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/em-scrollcaret) message each time you add more data.

Comment: You could use a *refresh timer* and only update the display after the timer elapses.  A lot of data can be gathered before a User will notice the change.  Maybe use a control that you can append to, but doesn't refresh the window.

Comment: Do you only want to consider solutions that display the data as text, or are you open to displaying it graphically instead?  (I ask because the human eye can process the meaning of an animated graphic much faster than it can read text)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Hey remi, sorry i should have clarified.  I have multi-line control enabled and i can technically scroll down.  The Issue is that every time I update the scroll bar defaults back to the top.  This might actually be an issue with how im populating the string.

Comment: @Chris ah yes, that can be annoying, but it also depends on HOW you are updating the text. For instance, if you are using `WM_SETTEXT` then that replaces the entire text in one go, and will scroll back to the top. You can use `EM_SCROLLCARET` to scroll back to the bottom. Or, you can use `EM_REPLACESEL` as I described in a comment to JBRWilkinson's answer. That does not scroll. But either way, be sure to disable screen repaints with `WM_SETREDRAW` while you are making updates, and then reenable when done.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Im currently using SetDlgItemText to update the specific edit control with the string i have.  SetdlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_MYEDITCONTROL, L"my string" as an example.  I attempted to use SendMessage with EM_SCROLLCARET but it causes a crash.  I currently have my data update within the message loop inside winmain just after the message handling.

Comment: @Chris `SetDlgItemText()` updates the entire text, which is not what you need in this situation. `EM_SCROLLCARET` should not be causing any crashes, especially since it doesn't take any input parameters. The only way it could crash is if your code (or the Edit control itself) is responding to scroll changes in an incorrect manner. Please [edit] your question to show the actual code you are having issues with.

Answer (score 2):

My idea is no point of updating the visual control as the same speed you receive the data. Because even-though you update at the same speed the users cannot see that change at the speed of data receiving. Human eye does not see a change happening in speed as 1/8th of a second. So better to update the visual control in a controlled manner. Maybe using a timer.

Answer (score 1):

Appending to the text of an edit control for each subsequent data point will lead to flickering as the whole control re-renders as the text has changed.

I'd advise one of the following options:

1) use a ListBox or ListView control; when you add another row item, it only re-draws the new/changed/scrolled item. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/create-a-simple-list-box and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/list-view-controls-overview

2) If you only want an always-scrolling list of data, consider just having a command-line application that writes to the standard output and saves you a lot of trouble - `cout` or `printf` your data.

Comment: "*Appending to the text of an edit control for each subsequent data point will lead to flickering as the whole control re-renders as the text has changed*" - you can avoid that by using [`EM_REPLACESEL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/em-replacesel) to insert new text at the end. Use `EM_SETSEL` or `EM_EXSETSEL` to move the caret to the end of the current text and remove any selection, then `EM_REPLACESEL` to insert at the current caret position.  If you are going to use a ListBox/ListView instead, consider using it in virtual mode, at least.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: It never ceases to amaze me how many problems have been encountered and solved by the native API designers, but the solution was completely lost and unavailable from (managed wrapper library of the month)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use EM_SETSEL and EM_SCROLLCARET to automatically scroll, but also check the position of the scroll bar before doing that. If not at the bottom, it means that the user wanted to pause, so you can scroll.

Also, you can have the scroll lock key checked in order whether to scroll or not, after all that is what it's name is supposed to do.